# "SameSite" attribute not changing on cloudfare website

Tags: cookies, jwt, hosting, cloudflare, samesite

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this so please let me know if I am wrong.

I have a site I am building hosted on cloudflare and the clients security team reported that the SameSite attribute for CF_Session (Cloudflare's JWT token) was coming up as "none".

In the cookie settings on cloudflare I have set SameSite = Strict but when I run a scan it is seen as = none.

Anyone had this issue before and now a solution for it?